# C++ - creating a thread within instances of classes inside the main() method and calling Sleep()

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-sleep

So I wanted to create a thread to be able to have parts of my program run independently of each other. (The only other way was to create an event based timer and I dont have time for that).

I can create a thread in the main method (entry point) of my application and it works as intended. That is, when I attach my thread to a function located in my main source file. It will call that function in a separate thread and so I can call Sleep() in that function by my program will continue executing code outside of that thread.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void makeThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(2000);
        printf("thread print");
    }
}  

int main()
{
    std::thread th(&makeThread);
    printf("normal print");
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
}
```

This code will print "normal print" before it prints "thread print". But when I try to create a thread within a class which I have instantiated in the Main class, this is not the case. I notice that it forces me to join the thread if it's not inside the main class, and as a result, I am unable to execute logic separately. How do I correctly call sleep() within a class so that only the thread I have created sleeps and not the main thread? This is my code for the thread created within a class used by main().

```
Alarm::Alarm(int cID, int port, string fileName) : ClientObserver(cID, port, fileName)
{
    std::thread th(&Alarm::runLoop, this);
    th.join();
}

void Alarm::runLoop()
{
    while(true)
    {
        bRaiseAlarm = true;
        Sleep(3500);
        if(bRaiseAlarm == true)
        {
            //Sound the alarm
            alarmStep = alarmStep >= 3 ? 1 : alarmStep + 1;
            printf("\nALARM FOR %c with alarm number: %i\n", fileName.c_str(), alarmStep);
            bRaiseAlarm = false;
        }
    }
}
```

In the following code, only the while(true) loop executes and the functionality of the rest of my program is halted because of the Sleep()

Comment: Make `th` a class member so it stays alive as long as your `Alarm` instance.  Alternatively you could call `th.detach()` before `th` goes out of scope.

Comment: FWIW, C++ has a standard sleep function: `std::this_thread::sleep_[for/until]`

Comment: @MilesBudnek Trying to define it in the header file creates obscure errors with my socket connection so I created a pointer to the thread instead with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a pointer to the thread was the first step. The pointer was needed because the variable th went out of scope. Joining the thread somehow solved the problem. Ridding that line solves the problem.